# get checkbox values from form and add to JSON string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

attempting to pull form values and put them into localStorage via JSON string.  This code works for everything but checkbox values.  How do i also get checkbox values?  Please and thanks!

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitOrder"> 
</form>

const userOrder = {};

function getValues(e) {
  // turn form elements object into an array
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.elements);

  // go over the array storing input name & value pairs
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    if(el.type !== "submit" && el.type !=="button") {
      userOrder[el.name] = el.value;
    }
  });

  // finally save to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('userOrder', JSON.stringify(userOrder));
}  

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", getValues);

console.log(localStorage.getItem('userOrder'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) serialize() function.
Then, you can do something like this:

```js
function onSubmit( form ){
  var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() ); //  <-----------

  console.log( data );

  return false;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
  <input name='user' placeholder='user'><br>
  <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='remember-me'>
  <br />
  <button type='submit'>Try</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the .checked attribute of a checkbox to tell if it is checked or not

```js
const userOrder = {};
function getValues(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // turn form elements object into an array
  //you can also use Array.from(e.target.elements)
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.elements);
  console.log(elements);
  // go over the array storing input name & value pairs
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    if(el.type == "checkbox") {
      userOrder[el.name] = el.checked;
    }
  });
  console.log(userOrder);
  // finally save to localStorage
  //localStorage.setItem('userOrder', JSON.stringify(userOrder));
}  

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", getValues);

//console.log(localStorage.getItem('userOrder'));
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitOrder"> 
</form>
```